# Difference result of rotation matrix in Vertex and Fragment shaders

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, webgl

I have a problem with rotation matrix.It gives different  results in Vertex and fragment shaders.

There are two objects.
First is sphere.Sphere needs its texture to be rotated in the fragment shader. It works fine and matches the GUI algorithm. Used exact same algorithm.

Second object is points (sprites). It should rotated around sphere by same angles.

I use  next algorithm in fragment and vertex shader:

```
mat3 rotateX = mat3(
   1.0, 0, 0,
   0, cos(angles.x), -sin(angles.x),
   0, sin(angles.x), cos(angles.x)
   );

   mat3 rotateY = mat3(
   cos(angles.y), 0, sin(angles.y),
   0, 1, 0,
   -sin(angles.y), 0, cos(angles.y)
   );

   mat3 rotateZ = mat3(
   cos(angles.z), -sin(angles.z), 0,
   sin(angles.z), cos(angles.z), 0,
   0, 0, 1
   );

   float Fi = (-current.x) * M_PI;
   float Te = current.y * M_PI;

   vec3 coord;
   coord.x = sin(Te) * cos(Fi);
   coord.y = sin(Te) * sin(Fi);
   coord.z = cos(Te);

   coord = vec3(coord.x, coord.y, coord.z) * rotateX * rotateY * rotateZ;
```

I have the following  problem. If making rotation from one any Axis, all is ok. If making rotation by two or three Axis then sphere and points rotate in difference directions.

Its normal behavior (start position and one axis rotation):
http://joxi.ru/JqkaVP3JTJA_Xelvbds

Its after begining rotation:
http://joxi.ru/qqoaVIwyTJBWeTcvy4A

What am I doing wrong?

Using WebGL (OpenGL ES2).

Comment: Why won't you just rotate the sphere mesh and point sprites with the same rotation matrix in the vertex shader?

Comment: Are you doing the multiplication in the same order in both shaders? In OpenGL it is more common to use Matrix * Vector. Vector * Matrix works too, but as if the matrix had been transposed. For a 3x3 matrix representing a rotation, the transposed matrix represents the same rotation in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Just need to multiply rotation matrix in reverse order.

Shader for fragment rotation

```
   mat3 rotateX = mat3(
   1.0, 0, 0,
   0, cos(angles.x), -sin(angles.x),
   0, sin(angles.x), cos(angles.x)
   );

   mat3 rotateY = mat3(
   cos(angles.y), 0, sin(angles.y),
   0, 1, 0,
   -sin(angles.y), 0, cos(angles.y)
   );

   mat3 rotateZ = mat3(
   cos(angles.z), -sin(angles.z), 0,
   sin(angles.z), cos(angles.z), 0,
   0, 0, 1
   );

   float Fi = (-cUv.x + 0.25) * 2.0 * M_PI;
   float Te = cUv.y * M_PI;  

   vec3 coord;
   coord.x = sin(Te) * cos(Fi);
   coord.y = sin(Te) * sin(Fi);
   coord.z = cos(Te);

   coord = coord * rotateX * rotateY * rotateZ;
```

Shader for vertex rotation

```
angles = -angles;

mat3 rotateX = mat3(
    1.0, 0, 0,
    0, cos(angles.x), -sin(angles.x),
    0, sin(angles.x), cos(angles.x)
);

mat3 rotateY = mat3(
    cos(angles.y), 0, sin(angles.y),
    0, 1, 0,
    -sin(angles.y), 0, cos(angles.y)
);

mat3 rotateZ = mat3(
    cos(angles.z), -sin(angles.z), 0,
    sin(angles.z), cos(angles.z), 0,
    0, 0, 1
);

float Fi = (-curPosition.x) * M_PI; //hor
float Te = (curPosition.y) * M_PI; //vert

vec3 coord;
coord.x = sin(Te) * cos(Fi);
coord.y = sin(Te) * sin(Fi);
coord.z = cos(Te);

return coord * rotateZ * rotateY * rotateX;
```